# How to setup path to access psql from command line in Mac

Tags: postgresql

psql does not work even path was set .bash_profile. Path was set export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin:$PATH in .bash_profile.

Comment: Have you tried running the command "echo $PATH"? What does it show?

Comment: Yes, It shows /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: But not your PostgreSQL path? Try putting your PATH line above into .bashrc. And then run "source .bashrc".

Comment: Yes, I did. Same warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your PATH line above into .bashrc. And then run "source .bashrc" (from your home directory). This is normally the file that is read on logging in to a bash shell.

You can then double check by running "echo $PATH" and your PostgreSQL path should now appear in the list of PATH directories.